# Arrays of pointer types are currently not supported Xamarin.UWP error

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am building a `Xamarin.Forms` application. I am trying to build my `Xamarin.UWP` version of the application.
The application builds fine in Debug mode but when I try to build it in release mode I get the following error:

> Error     ILT0042: Arrays of pointer types are not currently supported:
>   'System.Int16*[]'.**Arrays of pointer types are not currently
>   supported: 'System.Single*[]'.__Arrays of pointer types are not
>   currently supported: 'System.Int16*[]'.__Arrays of pointer types are
>   not currently supported: 'System.Int16*[]'.__Arrays of pointer types
>   are not currently supported: 'System.Single*[]'.__Arrays of pointer
>   types are not currently supported: 'System.Single*[]'.__Arrays of
>   pointer types are not currently supported: 'System.Int16*[]'.__Arrays
>   of pointer types are not currently supported:
>   'System.Single*[]'.** FieldStrikeMove.UWP

There is no file or line given with the error so I have no idea what is causing it or how to fix it.

The only other reference to this error I have found is here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69751/problems-with-building-and-deploying-my-projects

and here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/73169/uwp-10-build-fail-arrays-of-pointer-types-error

Has anyone seen this error?

Comment: Hi dude, did you find something? :/ **[I ask the same question here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152785/xamarin-forms-uwp-error-ilt0042-arrays-of-pointer-types-are-not-currently-s)**

Comment: @user1 Hi, could you please tell use more details? About your project, have you added reference to Newtonsoft.Json too in PCL?

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT I am referencing `NewtonSoft.Json` but only in my PCL, not in my UWP project. I have about 30-40 nuget packages on my project so its hard to pick which one is failing. I wouldn't have thought it was anything to do with `newtonsoft`. Although the project broke 2 days after adding the reference (automated build daily)

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT is there any way to get more information about the error? its not exactly clear where it is occuring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this link: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/217997/#Comment_217997

It turned out that something had added a reference to `Xamarin.iOS` to my `UWP` project.

Delete this reference and it will all work again

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem, that works for me. Without .Net Native tool chain it works fine

[image]