# Xamarin Forms UWP - Error : ILT0042: Arrays of pointer types are not currently supported

Tags: build, xamarin.forms, uwp, release

I got this error and.. nothing on the web ! It seems to come from [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)..

There is the `output` of my **PCL project**

```
1>  Newtonsoft.Json
1>  Imported XAML Roots from 2 files:
1>  C:\PROJECT_PATH\PROJECT.UWP\obj\ARM\Release\ilc\in\PROJECT.UWP.xr.xml
1>  C:\PROJECT_PATH\PROJECT.UWP\obj\ARM\Release\ilc\in\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP.xr.xml
1>C:\PROJECT_PATH\PROJECT.UWP\Resources.System.Linq.Expressions.rd.xml(35): warning : ILTransform_0027: Method 'CreateLambda' within 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' could not be found.
1>C:\PROJECT.UWP\Resources.System.Linq.Expressions.rd.xml(91): warning : ILTransform_0027: Method 'ParameterIsAssignable' within 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' could not be found.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Boolean Microsoft.Scripting.Generation.CompilerHelpers.MemberEquals(System.Reflection.MemberInfo, System.Reflection.MemberInfo)' at IL offset 0x3F.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Boolean Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectionUtils.MatchesFlags(System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo, System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' at IL offset 0x15.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Boolean Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectionUtils.MatchesFlags(System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo, System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' at IL offset 0x2E.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Boolean Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectionUtils.MatchesFlags(System.Reflection.MethodInfo, System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' at IL offset 0x15.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Boolean Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectionUtils.MatchesFlags(System.Reflection.MethodInfo, System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' at IL offset 0x2E.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Boolean Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectionUtils.MatchesFlags(System.Reflection.FieldInfo, System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' at IL offset 0x15.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Boolean Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectionUtils.MatchesFlags(System.Reflection.FieldInfo, System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' at IL offset 0x2E.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Boolean Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectionUtils.MatchesFlags(System.Reflection.EventInfo, System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' at IL offset 0xB4.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Boolean Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectionUtils.MatchesFlags(System.Reflection.EventInfo, System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' at IL offset 0xC9.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Boolean Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectionUtils.MatchesFlags(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo, System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' at IL offset 0x15.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Boolean Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectionUtils.MatchesFlags(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo, System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' at IL offset 0x2E.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Boolean Microsoft.Scripting.Utils.ReflectionUtils.MatchesFlags(System.Type, System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' at IL offset 0x20.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Security.Authentication.CipherAlgorithmType Security.Tls.MobileAuthenticatedStream.CipherAlgorithm.get()' at IL offset 0x24.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Security.Authentication.HashAlgorithmType Security.Tls.MobileAuthenticatedStream.HashAlgorithm.get()' at IL offset 0x24.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Security.Authentication.ExchangeAlgorithmType Security.Tls.MobileAuthenticatedStream.KeyExchangeAlgorithm.get()' at IL offset 0x24.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.IntPtr CoreText.CTParagraphStyle.CreateFromSettings(CoreText.CTParagraphStyleSettings)' at IL offset 0xCC.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): warning : ILTransform_0027: Invalid IL detected in method 'System.Int32 CoreAnimation.CATransform3D.GetHashCode()' at IL offset 0x22.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5): error : ILT0042: Arrays of pointer types are not currently supported: 'System.Int16*[]'.__Arrays of pointer types are not currently supported: 'System.Single*[]'.__Arrays of pointer types are not currently supported: 'System.Int16*[]'.__Arrays of pointer types are not currently supported: 'System.Int16*[]'.__Arrays of pointer types are not currently supported: 'System.Single*[]'.__Arrays of pointer types are not currently supported: 'System.Single*[]'.__Arrays of pointer types are not currently supported: 'System.Int16*[]'.__Arrays of pointer types are not currently supported: 'System.Single*[]'.__
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:01:17.24
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Does someone can help me? :/ I need to make this UWP version of my PCL project...

Comment: Hi Emixam, is this PCL created by Xamarin default project template? Looks like I can't reproduce your issue using Newtonsoft.Json V9.0.1. Could you create a simple demo which can repro this issue?

Comment: Ok, I'll try to make you an Edit ;)

Comment: @Emixam23 When did you start to see this error?

Comment: Yesterday... You know what, I got ride of this eror by recreating the project.. But now, the release is working but the image (Embedded Resource) doesn't work..

Comment: @Emixam23 So for the original issue, have you resolved? What's the meaning of image (Embedded Resource) doesn't work? Could you share your simple demo?

Comment: To be honest, I just install everything on VS2015 and then, remake a new project, copied every source and then, it worked fine... However, Compiling with .net throws this error unlike when I uncheck it... [Embedded Images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. It took me days to figure this out. To solve the problem, I had to comment out this line from my UWP.csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Xamarin.iOS\v1.0\Xamarin.iOS.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I can only assume that this line got added when I tried to add the following loading page recipe to my app. At one point, I tried to add it as a customer renderer to my UWP app and in doing so added using UIKIT, which is an iOS thing. I'm only speculating, but perhaps that is it. 
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message/

I also assume that it worked just fine under Debug, but didn't Build under Release due to the fact that the .Net Native tool chain option was trying to compile the Xamarin.iOS.dll with my UWP app.

I'm not saying that this is your issue, but perhaps there is a similar entry in your UWP.csproj file that is causing the issue. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have updated all the packages to the latest versions, you have Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and the latest stable version of Xamarin.

Some developers have mentions, that building release app packages can cause issues if you don't use the English version of Visual Studio - if you don't, set it in `Tools -> Options -> International Settings`.

Comment: Hi, ok, I'll give a try now, however, either my computer or my visual studio 2015 is in English. :) thank !