# How do I solve .net native compilation error ILT0042 for UWP App?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, monogame

I have a UWP game, built on MonoGame. When compiling a .net native build to submit to the store, I get the following error

> ILT0042: Arrays of pointer types are not currently supported:
>   'System.Byte*[]'.__

Some [Xamarin guys had the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39152785/xamarin-forms-uwp-error-ilt0042-arrays-of-pointer-types-are-not-currently-s), caused by including the wrong DLL. In both cases, the debug and release builds work. But when .net native is enabled, errors are thrown.

Is there additional logging available somewhere in Visual Studio, or Windows that can help narrow down the search? Anything that can give more information on this unhelpful error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a dummy project, and link all your supporting (if any) projects to it and rebuild.

Then start iterating through other references, and nuget packages, building each time. If it's an offending package update, then the this will expose it.

Comment: It was lz4net v1.0.15.93, installed via nuget. Once removed, I could build and upload to the Windows Store successfully. I'll reach out to the dev.